# How do I tell another civilization to move its army away from my cities?

Tags: civilization-6

I've had several different civilizations get upset at me and tell me to move my army away from their cities, and since I didn't feel like going to war right then, I have generally complied. However, one civilization has amassed a large army at a town that shares borders with one of mine, and a number of the units are on the border. Is there any way I can tell them to move away? I don't mind going to war with them, but I would like to at least delay it a few turns so I can complete a nuke and move in a few more units to protect myself better.

Comment: I remember in an older civilization (civ 3) that they had to actually be within your border before you could tell them to move.

Comment: @TimmyJim well in this case, neither of us have open borders, so if either of us were in the others borders it would be an act of war. And both times I have been told to move we weren't at war, and if we were I wouldn't move them.

Comment: Maybe they changed in across the games. In civ 3, you could let other people's troops into your border and war wouldnt be declared.  You could either tell them to leave, or ignore them.  I think if you crossed into another empires border they would instantly ask you to move, and you also had the option to negotiate open borders then.

Comment: @TimmyJim well, I have been at war off and on with them for the entire game, so I haven't opened borders with them, nor they with me. And when I failed to move them once, it said it was because I hadn't moved my troops away from their borders. This is the first time I have played a civilization game though.

Comment: Ah. I don't have the new one so I can't tell you for sure how it works. I vaguely remember that if you once went to war with someone, you were limited on what you could negotiate with them even after returning to peace. I could be wrong though.

Comment: In base civ5, you can't ask AIs to move armies away either, but in civ5 vox populi/cpp you can

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot.

After more playtime trying to find opportunities to demand this, and investigation online, there does not appear to be any way of demanding an AI move it's armies away.

This sounds like it would be under the "Discuss >" category on the Diplomacy screen alongside the other demands (like "stop converting me" and "don't settle near me"), but I have not seen it, nor has anyone that I have been able to find.

Comment: which seems ridiculous considering they will bitch about your army being too close when you are 2 cities (7+ tiles) away from their borders in your territory..

Comment: @Chieron Yes, it is ridiculous. I had assumed they would give us the ability to make that demand, but it seems not.